# Positive term series$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{1-\frac 1n}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

When I do my homework, I met this problem:

> If positive term series$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty  a_n$ is convergent,Prove:$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{1-\frac 1n}$ is convergent.

I have no idea about it.
Could someone give me a hint or prove it..Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the sum into two parts:
$$ \sum_{n \in A} a_n^{1-\frac1n} + \sum_{n \in \mathbb N \setminus A} a_n a_n^{-\frac1n} ,$$
where $A = \{n : a_n < 2^{-n}\}$.  Use one argument on one part, and another argument on the other part.

Comment: Beautiful proof,Thanks a lot!

Comment: @smallsmallice how to prove 2nd part for n not in A. for 1st part i can use abel theorem. pls clarify. I am learning real analysis

Comment: For the first part, use that $a_n^{1-1/n} < 2^{-n+1}$, not Abel's Theorem.  For the second part, use that $a_n^{-1/n} \le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Young's inequatity:
$$\frac{a_n^{1-\frac1n}}2=a_n^{1-\frac 1n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{\frac 1n}\leq\left(1-\frac1n\right)a_n+\frac{1}{n\cdot2^n}<a_n+\frac{1}{2^n},$$
so
$$a_n^{1-\frac 1n}<2a_n+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},\ n=1,2,\cdots.$$